# Can anybody explain "snipe" and "by spring" in this context for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I think Elizabeth Warren and Hillary Clinton will be **sniping** at each other **by spring**," predicts Valliere.

[source](http://money.cnn.com/2016/10/19/investing/elizabeth-warren-wall-street/index.html?iid=SF_LN)

I looked them up [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snipe) but still couldn't understand them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you get the impression that *by spring* is an idiom or fixed expression? Actually it's just the words *by* and *spring*. So we have three words here that are confusing you: *sniping* (present participle of the verb *to snipe*), *by* and *spring*.

[*To snipe*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snipe#Etymology_3) means:

- “To make malicious, underhand remarks or attacks.”

[By](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/by) means:

- “At some time before (the given time), or before the end of a given time interval.”

And [spring](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spring) is:

- One of the four seasons of the year. It follows winter and precedes summer.

Comment: Sniping is also what a sniper does; Chambers has "To shoot at individuals from a position of (usu distant) cover; To attack or criticize, esp from a position of security (figurative; often with at)"